# how to use selenium on web apps built with gradio?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, gradio

I am trying to click a button on selenium on a web app built using selenium. But ending up with error "element not found".

I want to click the submit button using selenium,
[image]

This is the code I am using,

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr.cursor-pointer:nth-child(1)")
```

error I am getting,

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: button.panel-button:nth-child(2)
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:183:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:395:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16
```

Only getting this error while trying to click button on wep page built using gradio, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What web page is it?

Comment: https://huggingface.co/spaces/akhaliq/ArcaneGAN

Comment: Hi, you might not need to scrap that app, Gradio by default exposes an API for the predict function, please look at the docs here https://hf.space/embed/akhaliq/ArcaneGAN/api